# Erlang: string to list

Tags: string, list, erlang

I have a two part question:

Part I:
I have a variable, "filtro_x", that has a string.
I want to convert that string ("1, 2, 3") into a list ([1, 2, 3]), so I can assign it to a new variable.

Part II:
Can I use this new variable directly in a query, like below?
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = ANY($1);

Can anybody please enlight me on how to go about it?

Thank you,
Rui

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st part, I managed to succeed with the following instruction:

```
[begin {Int,_}=string:to_integer(Token), Int end|| Token<-string:tokens(String," ")]
```

Now, working on the 2nd part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a variable, "filtro_x"

In Erlang, variables begin with a capital letter, and they don't have quotes around them.

> For the 1st part, I managed to succeed with the following instruction:

Your solution doesn't even work on the string you proposed in your question:

```
39> String = "1,2,3".                                                                    
"1,2,3"

40> Numbers = [begin {Int,_}=string:to_integer(Token), Int end|| Token<-string:tokens(String," ")]. 
[1]
```

Try this:

```
53> String1 = "1,2,3".                                                                           
"1,2,3"

54> Numbers = [ element(1, string:to_integer(Substr)) || Substr <- string:tokens(String1, ", ")]. 
[1,2,3]

59> String2 = "1,20, 130,4,     67".                                                              
"1,20, 130,4,     67"

60> Numbers = [ element(1, string:to_integer(Substr)) || Substr <- string:tokens(String2, ", ")]. 
[1,20,130,4,67]
```

> Can I use this new variable directly in a query, like below? SELECT
>   field1, field2, field3 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = ANY($1);

That's not Erlang.  If you are asking whether you can interpolate a variable into a string, you certainly can.  Use the `~s` control sequence:

```
88> String = "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = ANY(~s)".            
"SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = ANY(~s)"

89> Insert = "1,2,3".
"1,2,3"

90> Query = lists:flatten(io_lib:format(String, [Insert]) ).
"SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = ANY(1,2,3)"
```

Or:

```
92> String1 = "1,2,3".
"1,2,3"

93> Query = lists:flatten([
93>     "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = ANY(",
93>     String1,
93>     $) 
93> ]).
"SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = ANY(1,2,3)"
```